# How to change default stylesheet rules order in Internet Explorer Developer Tools

Tags: css, firebug, ie-developer-tools

One reason why I don't use Internet Explorer for web development is the way it supports CSS attribute manipulation: it lists the most general stylesheet attributes first. When there's a lot of the stylesheet rules you have to scroll down - which is most of the time.
Is there a way to change that order ? So it list the most specific style rules first just like Firefox in firebug and Chrome do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with IE tester. [www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

You also need to install debug toolbar for IE tester http://www.debugbar.com/download.php.

This tool will give you what you need.